# Java pad string with specific characters

Tags: java, string

I have a string `apple` I want it maximum 8 character long.

So i have `apple`. its `5` chars long.  I pad it with 3`*`  to make it `***apple`

So i have `bat`. its `3` chars long.  I pad it with 5`*`  to make it `*****bat`

Is there any way to do it? Cant find any padding library out there.

Comment: You're trying to add as many asterisk characters to the beginning of a string to make it at least 8 characters long?

Comment: yes, pad it to make it maximum 8 chars long

Comment: @RahulSK Did you mean "**minimum** 8 character long"? *Maximum* 8 long would mean that e.g. `relationship` should be *truncated* to `relation` or `tionship`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other way how you can do it:

```
String.format("%8s", "helllo").replace(' ', '*');
```

In this case you do not need to add library.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Built into [Java 11+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)#Version_history)

```
"*"                             // A single-character string.
.repeat( 8 - "apple".length )   // `String::repeat` multiplies text. Here we return a `String` of a certain number of asterisks.
.concat( "apple" ) ;            // Appends to those asterisks our original input.
```

> ***apple

## `String::repeat`

Java 11 brought a new method, [`repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)), to the `String` class. This method multiplies a piece of text a certain number of times. Multiplying by zero is valid, resulting in an empty string.

In our case, we want to multiply a single character string, `*`.

```
int goal = 8 ; 
String input = "apple" ;
int length = input.length() ;
String output = "*".repeat( goal - length ).concat( input ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Jlhpfb).

> ***apple

Comment: This solution is much less verbose and requires no external lib. Plus Juan.

Comment: How about "strawberry" instead of "apple"?

Comment: @saka1029 Passing a negative number to `String::repeat` throws a `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringUtils.leftPad](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad-java.lang.String-int-char-) from Apache Commons Lang library

```
StringUtils.leftPad(null, *, *)     = null
StringUtils.leftPad("", 3, 'z')     = "zzz"
StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 3, 'z')  = "bat"
StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 5, 'z')  = "zzbat"
StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 1, 'z')  = "bat"
StringUtils.leftPad("bat", -1, 'z') = "bat"
```

Comment: You should mention that this requires Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0):

No library needed. Uses a `StringBuilder` and `reverse()` for speed (insert is slower than append):

```
public String padWord(String word)
{
    if(word.length() < 8)
    {
        StringBuilder foo = new StringBuilder(word);
        foo = foo.reverse();
        for(int x = word.length(); x < 8; x++)
        {
            foo.append('*');
        }
        foo.reverse();
    }
    return foo.toString();
}
```